# passing two dimensional array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a problem with passing my created table to fillMatrix function. 
Another thing is how to refer to this table in my function. I really appreciate every kind of help. I didn't get any console problem. Program is freezing.

```
int **createTable(int n) 
{
    int **table = new int*[n]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        table[i] = new int[n];
    }
    return table;
}

void fillMatrix(int n, int **tab) 
{
    for(int x = 0; x<=n; x++)
    {
        for(int y= 0; y<=n; y++)
        {
            tab[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
}  


int main()
{
    int n;
    cout <<"Add size of table";
    cin >> n;
    int **table = createTable(n);

    srand(time(NULL));

    fillMatrix(n, table);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't tell us what kind of problem you have. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? Do you get a compiler error? Which one?

Comment: You should free the memory pointed to by `table`.

Comment: I didn't get any console problem. Program is freezing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see only one problem in your code:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++)
{
    for(int y = 1; y <= n; y++)
    {
        tab[x][y] = 0;
    }
}
```

Arrays in C++ are zero-based, but you tried to assign `tab[n][n]` which causes *undefined behavior*.

Also, you should `delete` your array once it is no longer needed.

---

As another solution I suggest you use `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake i should not copy and paste my code :D thanks for solving a problem.

Comment: @user1769428, Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

it is what they told you about. Your for statement should be like this

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
```

instead of

```
for( int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++ )
```

The compiler want warn you if you accidentally go beyond the size of an array thats why you didnt have any warnings or errors.

Think about using a vector instead of an array as suggested above.